# RxJava Subjects Vs Processors

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have been using Subjects in Rxjava for quite awhile but today a new term came up:

[PublishProccessor](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/PublishProcessor.html) would you please explain me the difference of the Processors and Subjects?

I have gone through the Docs but they are mostly the same.

thank you in advance

Comment: 2.1.15 updated the javadocs that should indicate quite clearly what each of them do or is capable of. Please read them again carefully and also compare their marbles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the Future readers:

The main difference is their base class, therefore the way that these two react to onNext event is different.

PublishProcessor is subclassed from Flowables so you can use a BackPressure Strategy when you make use of them.
PublishSubject's superclass is Observable so at very least there is no BackPressure Strategy.

Comment: Backpressure is the only difference?  I thought Processor acts like an Observable + Observer... hence it can be used as a message bus.

Comment: subjects and processors can be used the same way AFAIK. but when I looked at the source code the only difference to my eyes was actually the BackPressure.
maybe I'm mistaking!